# Headshots in Orcs Must Die?

Tags: orcs-must-die

I am wondering if are there any benefits in making headshots in Orcs Must Die!? I mean except the fact that you can take down an orc faster.

Comment: Isn't that actually the point? Kill them faster to finish the map faster? :p I mean spamming works but your aim goes way off, shooting concentrated bursts at their heads will work way better.

Comment: @Rafael I am [not sure](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32180/how-are-points-calculated-in-orcs-must-die) that total points only depends on how much time you take to complete the stage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no real benefit of headshots game play-wise, other than killing the enemies faster.

However, if you're looking to get a decent high score racked up, the headshots can be usable in a few ways:

- Keeping the killstreak going between traps.
- Getting a higher combo multiplier.

Note: Both of these points can be done without headshots, thus making it a lot harder. However, it does also require a lot of skill, to hit the headshots at the exact time you need to.