# What are combos and kill streaks?

Tags: orcs-must-die

I've noticed that, while I'm killing orcs, it will pop up with my current kill streak quite often, and, much more rarely, say my combo. I seem to get money for both and maybe points, but what are they defined as?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- A combo is when an orc dies from 2 or more methods at the same time. For example, a tar trap slowing them down and a clockwork mace gibbing them will count as a combo.
- A kill streak is when you kill many orcs within a small time period. If you continue killing orcs within a second (or so) of one another, your kill streak increments. Once you've gone a second (or so) without killing an orc, you are given a bonus based on the number of orcs you killed in that streak.

Comment: Does 'killed' in your 2nd bullet mean include those killed by your traps?

Comment: @Jeff Yes, it does. In fact, it's usually easier to get a kill streak with traps than with your weapon alone.