# How does scoring work in Orcs Must Die 2? (getting the high-scores)

Tags: orcs-must-die-2

My friend and I were able to get in the leaderboard top 100 on the later levels *(likely because it's only been out a day)* by spamming coin-forges and using coin-trinkets.  However, the top few scores still have 3 **TIMES** (!?!) as many points as we do.  Also, in the first couple of levels, we can't even break 2,000th place.

I have a feeling we're doing something wrong.  **How does the scoring work?  How do the top players get *so* many points?**

Comment: The loading tips say that increasing combos and killstreaks can double or triple your score.  I believe combos are initiated by several different traps damaging the orcs at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I can't confirm this because I haven't played enough, but it seems like the scoring is pretty similar to OMD 1, so you might find [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32180/how-are-points-calculated-in-orcs-must-die) useful. It links to a post on [Robot Entertainments blog](http://www.robotentertainment.com/blog/detail/Mastering-Leaderboards) that has the point values for various combos and whatnot.

Aside from, getting high combo scores has been the best for points as far as I can tell. So combine a lot of different trap types with magic/attacks to get higher scores, each type of different damage source should increase your combo (ie, combo only increases once per type of trap that hits an enemy). I don't believe that coin forges actually help with your score, they just increase the amount of coins you have to spend during that level, so replace them with tar/fire traps to increase your combo multipliers.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get #113 on Chasm, more or less by raw chance.  Most of my score was from "Skull Score", which got me a bonus 100,000 points, apparently because I picked up 11 bonus skulls (and one for getting my first 5-skull victory).